# How to fix Django TemplateDoesNotExist Error?

Tags: python, django

[image: image description here]

[image]
check the below images. I'm new to Django. I just tried to run a project downloaded from internet.

The below is code for index.html

```
{% extends 'HealthCare/homebase.html' %} {% load static %} {% block content %}
{% comment %}

{% endcomment %}
{% comment %} Take Appointment {% endcomment %}

{% comment %}


{% endcomment %} {% comment %} {% include "HealthCare/admin_doctor_patient_card.html" %} {% endcomment %} {% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/67579). [edit] the question and include code fragments with the *code sample* button (`{}`).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like author path is absolute and your path is not the same. Find the TEMPLATES setting on settings.py and fix if is it.